# CSS Select first occurrence of a class only

Tags: css, css-selectors

I need to add a style to the first occurrence of a class (`.border`) but not the others.

HTML

```
<div class="col">
  <div>
    <div class="border">
      <section>
        <div>
          <div>
            <div class="border">No Border</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div>
          <div>
            <div class="border">No Border</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.col{
  padding: 100px;
}
.col section{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  padding: 50px;
}

.col .border{
  border: solid;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/stemon/qw9ezu2h/2/

Comment: you can try `.col > div > .border{  border: solid; }`

Comment: can you try this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First method**

use **direct child(>) selector** in CSS.

```
.col > div >.border{
  border: solid;
}
```

```css
.col{
  padding: 100px;
}
.col section{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  padding: 50px;
}

.col > div >.border{
  border: solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="col">
  <div>
    <div class="border">
      <section>
        <div>
          <div>
            <div class="border">No Border</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div>
          <div>
            <div class="border">No Border</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Second method**

simply use `.col section .border{}` get second and third occurenece of class `border` to disable border to them by,

```
.col .border{
  border: solid;
}
.col section .border{
  border:none;
}
```

```css
.col{
  padding: 100px;
}
.col section{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  padding: 50px;
}

.col .border{
  border: solid;
}
.col section .border{
  border:none;
}
```

```html
<div class="col">
  <div>
    <div class="border">
      <section>
        <div>
          <div>
            <div class="border">No Border</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div>
          <div>
            <div class="border">No Border</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should to do this:

```
.col > div > .border{
    ... your code...
}
```

Comment: Apparently it has been almost at the same time